# How to hide some menu items - Zend Navigation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-navigation

I am using zend navigation in my site and I have the following navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<nav>
  <page1>
    <label>Site</label>
    <uri>/</uri>
    <pages>
        <page1_1>
            <label>Home</label>
            <uri>/</uri>
        </page1_1>
        <page1_2>
            <label>News</label>
            <uri>/news</uri>
        </page1_2>
        <page1_3>
            <label>Contact</label>
            <uri>/contact</uri>
        </page1_3>
    </pages>
  </page1>
 </nav>
</config>
```

Then I render the menu like below

```
<?=$this->navigation()->menu();?>
```

Output

```
- Site  
 - Home   
 - News  
 - Contact
```

Wanted Output

```
- Site  
 - Home    
 - Contact
```

How can I remove News item from the menu without affect other menu rendering?

Answer (score 3):

Vou can hide menu entries with visible flag, that you add to the entry you would like to hide, in your case `<page1_2>...</page1_2>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <nav>
    <page1>
      <label>Site</label>
      <uri>/</uri>
      <pages>
        ...
        <page1_2>
          <label>News</label>
          <uri>/news</uri>
          <visible>0</visible>
        </page1_2>
        ... 
      </pages>
    </page1>
  </nav>
</config>
```

Only use `0` or `1` within the xml file because `false` or `true` aren't recognized. All possible options you will find at [Zend Framework: Documentation: Pages - Zend Framework Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.pages.html).

If you want the invisible entry in the breadcrumbs menu you can temporally disable the visible flag by adding `setRenderInvisible( true )`

```
<?= $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setRenderInvisible( true ); ?>
```

All options of this helper you find [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation).

Comment: I don't want to hide it in all menus. Settting visible apply to all menus

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<visible>0</visible>
```

Comment: I don't want to hide it in all menus. Settting visible apply to all menus